# RegEx: Select space

Tags: regex, textwrangler

Given the following string:

```
<Node type="java script">dataSetRow["Invoice Number"]</Node>
<Node type="java script">dataSetRow["Invoice Number 2"]</Node>
```

How would remove the space in between the brackets using regex in a text editor? For example, dataSetRow["Invoice Number"] would be come dataSetRow["InvoiceNumber"]. So far, the best I can do is match all the text between the brackets.

```
(?<=dataSetRow\[)(.*)(?=\])
```

However, I can't seem to match just the spaces so that I can remove them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step instruction:

1. Open **Find and Replace** dialog
2. Check **Use Grep**
3. In **Search For**, type `(\[[^\]]*?)\s+`
4. In **Replace With**, type `\1`
5. Click **Replace All** *several* times until no further replacements are performed (i.e. no matches are found).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what editor you're using - in vim I would do it like this:

```
:1,$ s/(\["\S*)\s+(\S*"\])/\1\2/
```

or something like that - I always have to remind myself when vim needs backslashes and when it doesn't like for the parens...

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, but it might just be because I'm using TextWrangler instead of Vim. I'll keep playing around with it. Thanks for the suggestion!